# Database design according to the organization chart

Tags: mysql, database-design, erd

I'm trying to convert a organization chart into a database model where entities are (Sections, Employees and Projects)
[image]
With conditions:

1. An Employee works in only 1 Section while a Section may have many Employees working in it.
2. A Section may have only 1 Manager but a Manager can manage multiple sections.
3. A Section can have multiple project and a project can be assigned to one or more sections.

I have created the following ERD:

[image]

In my model, I have included managers & employees in one table(because all have to login for dashboard) but it creates problems, I need expert guidance for the Employee, Manager & Section relationship.

Should there be separate table for managers ?

Comment: _but it creates problems_ what problems? Changes I suggest at this point are: 1. Add a self referencing hierarchy table to model the org hierarchy. This is a table that just has the columns `u_id` and `parent_u_id` and references itself to model the org hierarchy. Also I'm not a fan of prepenending every column in the table with a special identifier. There's no point to this. If each user can only be in one section then the user table should have a section id in it. If section to project is many to many then you need a bridge table in the middle. So you need two new tables as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

No, since managers are users. The one thing that will upset the apple cart is this, how do you cater for the change in managers over the duration of a project/projects? This design assumes no fluidity in staff changes which is in my view a flawed assumption. You should maybe consider some type of slow-changing dimension table related to section - that represents section_heads that allows you to get the section head at a point in time. (The real world gets messy...) Best of luck.